# Large image is not uploading on server in base64 using php

Tags: php, json, image, base64

I have made a Api in which i have to upload the image of base64 format,
but when i try to upload large image(820 KB) in base64 format it is showing 
500 internal server error & if i tried to upload the small image(16 KB) then it
is uploaded successfully.I have also check the server upload size limit
it is 64mb.I am not getting why it is not uploading large base64 image string.
Below is my json request and php code of api.

PHP Code

```
<?php
 $jsonreq = $app->request->getBody();
 $encodedata = json_decode($jsonreq, true);
 $userid = !empty($encodedata['userid']) ? $encodedata['userid'] : '';
        $goal = !empty($encodedata['goal']) ? $encodedata['goal'] : '';
        $title = !empty($encodedata['title']) ? addslashes($encodedata['title']) : '';
        $category = !empty($encodedata['category']) ? $encodedata['category'] : '';
        $story = !empty($encodedata['story']) ? $encodedata['story'] : '';
        $image = !empty($encodedata['photo']) ? $encodedata['photo'] : '';
        $db = getDB();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where id='" . $userid . "'";
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $obj = new stdClass();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            if ($image != "" || $image != NULL) {
                $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
                $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
                $fileName = uploadBase64Image($userid, $img, uploadFundraiserImage);
                $imagepath = uploadFundraiserImage . $fileName;
                $imagepath = str_replace('../', '', $imagepath);
            } else {
                $imagepath = '';
            }

?>
```

Below is my json request

```
  {
    "goal":22,
    "title":"test new2",
    "story":"test new2",
    "category":"health",
    "userid":"46",
    "photo":"here we paste base64 image string"  
    }
```

Here if we take large image for example my imge size is 800 kb for the below base64 string then it shows 500 internal server error for below string.I can't able to paste bas64 string because it quite long but if we take a image of 800kb or more than this than it shows the following error.

```
500 Internal Server Error
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.
```

Comment: Did you check "max_post_size" in your php.ini?

Comment: yes it is also 65M.

Comment: Check your servers error log, typically /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: On Server : Through Putty : tail - f /var/log/apache2/error.log if using core ftp or filezilla or winscp, than just go folder to folder.

Comment: Side note: with a carefully crafted JSON payload it's possible to upload a picture for any user on your system. I suggest you address your SQL injection issues ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just turned off ModSec on my domain.After that its working fine its a server configuration error there is no error in code.

Comment: is it about mod security ? but why should we have to turn off that :(